# Speech synthesis web-API lagging only in Windows (7,8,10)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a tts chrome extension that works with the speech synthesis utterance  api. The text is selected on the basis of mouse hover. The extension works great in Ubuntu as well as macOS but on windows there is certain lag. When hovering from one DOM element to another, the browser freezes for a little amount of time and doesnt speak. Then if I move to another element from there, it speaks normally. E.g. - On mouse move on 'p' tag -tts works . Then on mouse move on 'li' tag - browser freezes and tts doesnt work. Then, if I move te mouse to the 'p' tag again the tts works.

The lag is skipping every alternate text from being spoken and is only being a problem in Windows. The stop speaker commands are all working well. Any suggestions?

This is a small sample of how the text is being spoken:

```
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            var msgtext = target.text();
            var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msgtext);
            speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    });
```

Comment: Any chance to view some of the extension code?

Comment: @Miguel I've added it in.